# Error: Could not find or load main class after adding dependency (maven)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In Java project I use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) as a project manager.
To my project's pom.xml file I add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0-M01</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to run the project I get an error:

> Could not find or load main class 'package.className'

I'm using Eclipse 4.2 Keppler with m2e plugin.

Comment: Please clean and rebuild the project, that will solve it

Comment: How are you trying to run the project?

Comment: I removed ~/~/.m2/repository folder and in Eclipse right-click on project Maven->Update Project... - it works.
I'm not sure if clean and rebuild project will help but probably yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Debian (probably other linux too) you should remove ~/~/.m2/repository folder and in Eclipse right-click on project Maven->Update Project...

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse work bench mode select the project and then click Alt+F5 to update Maven dependencies for the project.Please let me know if it resolves the issue

Comment: I didn't check it because I did what I write in previous post.