# After converting to maven getting error : Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Suddenly I got an error when converting to maven.
I create a simple java project, run main class, get results.
After converting to maven - I got error :  Could not find or load main class.

I tried deleting eclipse and its folder and download it again and get the same error.
Do you know what can be the problem?

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

What I have noticed is that when I covert the project to maven, the maven did not create 'Maven Managed Dependencies'. Moreover I click on configure build path --> Add library --> Maven Managed Dependencies . and it does not add the folder.

[image: Application Tree]

Comment: Did you do a Maven install after converting the project? Also try Project>Clean...

Comment: I did noe clean install and then the pom throw an exception : Description Resource Path Location Type
C:\Projects\try\target\classes\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path specified) pom.xml /try line 1 Maven Configuration Problem
@Aurasphere

Comment: @Aurasphere  I did clean install and then get an error on pom : 
Description Resource Path Location Type
C:\Projects\try\target\classes\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path specified) pom.xml /try line 1 Maven Configuration Problem

Comment: Please add your pom.xml to your post, it can help

Comment: Maybe a duplicate post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454004/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-after-adding-dependency-maven

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Right click on the project > Properties > Maven > Java EE Integration > Uncheck the option "Maven Archiver generates files under the build directory".

This should fix it. If it doesn't try Maven clean and install again.

Comment: I dont have Java EE integration under maven.Just Lifecycle mapping.

Comment: Show project tree : your class Main is in src/main/java ?